# Hyperlink in jqgrid on each cell of a particular column

Tags: jquery, jakarta-ee, dom-events

I have a treegrid where there are 10 columns like id, parentid, name etc.

Suppose 'parentid' is a hyperlink then when I select a cell  on 'parentid' the control should go to the cell of 'name' column corresponding to that 'parentid'.

For example if ' name' abc   corresponds to 'id' 2 then on clicking 2 on 'parentid' column,the control should  go to 'abc' in 'name' column.

I hope the question is clear.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your question, I'm sorry. But it looks like you will have to do something like

```
id.bind('click',function() { name.trigger('click'); }
```

Basically, capture the click event of parent id column and trigger a click event on which ever column you want to control.

I'm still not sure if that is what you need. Look at jquery bind and trigger functions. That will probably help you